# Scraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, magrittr

In this [rvest tutorial](http://blog.rstudio.com/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/), the author explains how to get titles and authors of recent message board postings for the Lego movie:

```
library(rvest)
lego_movie <- html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")

lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[3]] %>%
  html_table()
```

I understand that `[[3]]` in the second last line refers to the third element. However, what does the `.` in front do?

Comment: Well, I get only 2 elements with that and `.` can be considered as result of operation before that which in this case is `lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes("table")`. So it is 3rd element of `lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes("table")`.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe there were some changes to the IMDB site since the tutorial was written.

Comment: But thanks for explaining that `.` is the result of operation before that. Hit the bullseye as to what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ronak Shah has already pointed you to the answer, but in case anyone gets to this question I tried to give a more in-depth answer to the question.

At the beginning of the tutorial we are told the following:

> rvest is new package that makes it easy to scrape (or harvest) data from html web pages, inspired by libraries like beautiful soup. **It is designed to work with magrittr so that you can express complex operations as elegant pipelines** composed of simple, easily understood pieces.

I highlighted the relevant part of the text. As you may already have guessed, the `%>%` symbols are part of the `magrittr` library and are used to create the pipes.

The dot (`.`) in `.[[3]]` is used to help us create those **elegant pipelines** that the tutorial refers to. The dot's purpose is to be a substitute for the previous element in the pipeline. So, we can say that you could substitute:

```
third_element_in_table_node <- lego_movie %>%
                              html_nodes("table") %>%
                              .[[3]]
```

by:

```
table_node <- lego_movie %>%
              html_nodes("table")
third_element_in_table_node <- table_node[[3]]
```

Hope that helped! Happy scraping!